# DB2 Runtime Error

Tags: runtime, db2

```
UPDATE
      S
SET

    (S.a,
    S.b,
    S.c)
=
(

SELECT 
    FS.a,
    FS.b,
    FS.c
FROM

(SELECT 
    T.a,            
    T.b,                
    T.c,                    
    T.d,            
    T.e,                
    CASE 
        WHEN IS.a IS NULL THEN 'N'
        ELSE 'Y'
    END 

FROM 
    t       T
        JOIN
           y
          ON(y.a = T.a)




) FS


WHERE
    FS.a    = S.e
    AND FS.b    = S.a
    AND FS.c    = S.b
    AND FS.d    = S.c
)
```

While i execute this query iam getting an error :

```
 21:23:59  [UPDATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -811, SQL State: 21000]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.50.152
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.000/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

Can u please explain me the root cause...?

Answer (score 3):

All DB2 messages and their meanings can be found online.

In your case, according to the writeup for [SQL0811N](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.msg.doc/doc/sql0811.htm):

One of the following caused the error:

- Execution of an embedded SELECT INTO or VALUES INTO statement resulted in a result table of more than one row.

  Execution of a scalar fullselect resulted in a result table of more than one row.

This means that your select statement that starts:

```
SELECT 
FS.a,
FS.b,
FS.c
FROM ...
```

returns more than one row.  This isn't allowed since you're trying to set a single row's values in the update statement.